# In my show.blade.php file when I loop over $category->posts I would like to exclude the post that is being displayed by view

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my blade.php file that is displaying a single post is working perfectly well. In the blade I also have the access of the categories associated with the post i.e `$post->categories` and is working too.

The single post that I'm displaying from the .blade.php with a title in the header has got only one category and that is football.

When I loop over the posts title associated with the category of the post being displayed from the .blade.php file using the code below it works well and I get the titles of the posts associated with the category football as expected!

```
 @foreach($post->categories as $category)
        @foreach($category->posts as $post)
            <p>{{ $post->title }}</p>
                <br>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

MY CHALLENGE: I'd  like to exclude the title of the post that is also the title of the post of being displayed so that I don't repeat a title at the bottom of my page that was already in the header of the page.

MY CONTROLLER!

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Model\user\post;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
    class PostController extends Controller
    {
        public function post(post $post)
        {
    
            return view('user.post', compact('post'));
        }
    }
```

MY Post Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\user;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\user\Tag', 'post_tags')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\user\Category', 'category_posts');
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
}
```

My Category Model

```
   

     <?php
        
        namespace App\Model\user;
        
        use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
        
        class Category extends Model
        {
            public function posts()
            {
                return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\user\post', 'category_posts');
        
            }
        
            public function getRouteKeyName()
            {
                return 'slug';
            }
        }
```

my Category_post Model

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Model\user;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class Category_post extends Model
    {
        public function posts()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\user\Post', 'category_posts');
        }
    
    }
```

Please note that everything is working perfectly fine. When I loop over $category->posts title in my .blade.php file I get the posts title as expected. Now I just want to exclude the title of the post that is rendered by the blade.php file

Comment: Can you please show the controller logic

Comment: @FunkyMonk91  I've edited and added the controller to the post!

Comment: Interesting. I think the problem stems a bit deeper. Could you show the relationship in your Post model to the categories? Thanks.

Comment: @ FunkyMonk91 I have added that in the post!

please note that everything is working perfectly fine. When I loop over $category->posts title in my .blade.php file I get the posts title as expected. Now I just want to exclude the title of the post that is rendered by the blade.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach solves the problem by adding the except method in the loop. You can also check out @FunkyMonk91 approach in the comments which also solves the problem by achieving the same objective in the controller!

```
  @foreach($post->categories as $category)
         @foreach($category->posts->except($post->id) as $catPost)
         <p>{{ $catPost->title }}</p>
         <br>
         @endforeach
     @endforeach
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections?fbclid=IwAR1mnWJX5eCtXRbNnac7nAFUtR_Onk35Gqf7GRBweoz88iBQqZRGo65A-jg

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you are loading all the posts based off the one you want to show, via the relationship of `$post->belongsTo(Category::class)` (this is what I imagine your Post model looks like)

What I would do is this.

### In my controller:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function post(post $post)
    {
        // eager load the categories and their posts
        $post->load([
            'categories',
            // need to pass the selected post into the scope of the callback
            'categories.posts' => function ($query) use ($post) {
                // give us all the posts, besides this one, that belong to the category
                $query->where('id', '!=', $post->id)
            }
        ]);

        return view('user.post', compact('post'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having difficulties understanding your proposed solution!

Comment: Currently you are passing the single post to the page, then it's having to make an additional sql request to the server to the the post's parent category's child posts. We are moving that logic into the controller via the load function. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading I am then filtering the category's posts to exclude the initial one that the page loaded for.

Comment: But the post you are excluding in the controller I need it's body and title as main content in the post view! How do I access that in the view again?

Comment: Just add the $post->load() section of my solution to your controller function called post. Let me know how it goes :). This shouldnt be excluding anything. You can still access the post itself, this is just getting the selected post's categories, and those categories posts. There is no select statement, so all those category->posts should have ALL their data.

Comment: That has worked thanks. I've also found another alternative and that is by using an except method only in the loop as shown below!





`@foreach($post->categories as $category)
       @foreach($category->posts->except($post->id) as $catPost)
       <p>{{ $catPost->title }}</p>
       <br>
       @endforeach
@endforeach`

Comment: Very nice! I personally like to keep that sort of thing contained in the controller, but I'm glad you found a solution!